# MySQL 8.0.6 Recursive Query -- Omit leaf nodes from result set

Tags: mysql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have this master users table in MySQL:

```
u_id      u_name     unit_head    rep_mgr    dom_mgr 
10        alex         1            1          1
11        andrew       10           10         10
12        neena        10           11         10
13        steven       10           11         11
14        stephen      10           12         12
15        king         20           12         20
16        david        10           15         12
17        bruce        10           15         12
18        daniel       20           20         20         
19        nancy        20           18         18
20        luis         20           10         10
21        john         10           17         17
22        shelli       10           17         17
23        karen        10           22         17
24        mathew       20           19         19
25        adam         10           22         22
```

I need a query in which if I'm passing user id 10 in where condition, I want all the users who has immediate reportees in hierarchy based.

```
eg: 

  Alex
    Andrew
       Neena
         King
```

I have attached an image to explain the hierarchy.

```
      [Required_Hierarchy]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioIt7.jpg

The query should end when the last of users has no reportees.

I tried this query. But its showing all the users and level instead.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_connect_by AS (
     SELECT 1 AS level, CAST(CONCAT('-> ', u_name) AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS connect_by_path, usr.* 
       FROM users usr WHERE u_id =10
     UNION ALL
     SELECT level + 1 AS level, CONCAT(connect_by_path, ' / ', usr.employee_first_name ,' ',usr.employee_last_name) AS connect_by_path, usr.* 
       FROM cte_connect_by r INNER JOIN users usr ON  r.u_id = usr.rep_mgr
  )
  SELECT u_id, u_name, level,connect_by_path path
  FROM cte_connect_by
  ORDER BY 3;

Output

u_id   u_name    level   path
10     alex      1       -> alex
11     andrew    2       -> alex / andrew
12     neena     2       -> alex / neena
13     stephen   3       -> alex / neena / stephen
16     david     4       -> alex / neena / king / david
17     bruce     4       -> alex / neena / king / bruce
21     john      5       -> alex / neena / king / bruce / john
22     shelli    5       -> alex / neena / king / bruce / shelli
25     adam      6       -> alex / neena / king / bruce / shelli / adam
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: *Omit leaf nodes from result set* Add according WHERE EXISTS to CTE subqueries which detects that the node have a child and hence is not a leaf.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. If you can give a small example it would be great.